# Nova Computer Service WIll Not Start: libvirtError: XML error: Missing CPU model name

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, openstack

I am having a problem with the Nova compute service not starting. I found tons of other people with this question, but nobody seems to have figured out the problem:

```
systemctl status openstack-nova-compute.service
● openstack-nova-compute.service - OpenStack Nova Compute Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openstack-nova-compute.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-04-20 11:32:56 EDT; 2s ago
 Main PID: 19966 (nova-compute)
   CGroup: /system.slice/openstack-nova-compute.service
           └─19966 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/nova-compute

Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 141, in proxy_call
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: rv = execute(f, *args, **kwargs)
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 122, in execute
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: six.reraise(c, e, tb)
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 80, in tworker
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3505, in baselineCPU
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: if ret is None: raise libvirtError ('virConnectBaselineCPU() failed', conn=self)
Apr 20 11:32:56 ose-osp.dc2.crunchtools.com nova-compute[19966]: libvirtError: XML error: Missing CPU model name
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the guest VM by adding the following to the "domain type='kvm'" section:

```
virsh edit machine.example.com

 <cpu mode='host-passthrough'>
   <model fallback='forbid'/>
   <topology sockets='2' cores='1' threads='1'/>
 </cpu>
```

Option: For nested OpenStack, modify nova.conf

```
 vi /etc/nova/nova.conf

 virt_type=kvm
 cpu_mode=host-passthrough
```